# $state.go not redirecting to page

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a login and registration for somebody who already has a website. Not sure if it matters but `index.html` is the landing page and I click on login to goto the login page. The rest of the project is not apart of the web app only login and register so far (index.html doesnt have any angularjs code and it is not loading any of the controllers or app.js).

On login a response is returned from the server but it doesn't go to the `test` page but the url changes from `http://express.app/dashboard/login.html#!/` to `http://express.app/dashboard/login.html#!/test` I have no idea why the `#!/` is being added in the first place. However if I look in my network console I can see that `test.html` is being loaded and if I look at the preview I can see the page.

I have tried many different combos like setting `templateURL` to `dashboard/test.html` and just leaving it as `/test.html` but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

app.js

```
angular.module('app',['angular-jwt','angular-storage', 'ngRoute', 'ui.router'])
  .config(function  ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider, $httpProvider, jwtOptionsProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
      .state("login", {
          url:"/login",
          controller: "loginController",
          templateUrl: "dashboard/login.html"
      })
      .state("signup", {
          url:"/signup",
          controller: "signupController",
          templateUrl: "dashboard/register.html"
      })
      .state("test", {
          url:"/test",
          controller: "testController",
          templateUrl: "test.html"
      });

  jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function (store) {
      return store.get('jwt');
  };
      jwtOptionsProvider.config({
          whiteListedDomains: ['express.api', 'localhost']
  });

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
})
  .run(function($rootScope, $state, store, jwtHelper) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
      if (to.data && to.data.requiresLogin) {
          if (!store.get('jwt') || jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(store.get('jwt'))) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $state.go('login');
          }
      }
});
```

login.Controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http, $state, store) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.login = function() {
      $http({
          url: 'http://expressapi.com/login',
          method: 'POST',
          data: $scope.user
      }).then(function(response) {
          console.log("res", response.data.token);
          store.set('jwt', response.data.token);
          var test1 = store.get('jwt');
          console.log("get", test1);
          $state.go("test");
      }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
          alert(error);
      });
  }
});
```

test.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
  .controller('testController', function ($scope, $http, $state, store) {
     console.log("TEst");
      $scope.test = function() {
      }
});
```

login.html

```
<body class="main" ng-app="app" ng-controller="loginController">
  <div class="form" data-ix="new-interaction-2">
    <label class="field-label" for="Name-2">Email</label>
      <input class="text-field-2 w-input" data-name="name" id="Name-2" maxlength="256" name="name" placeholder="Email" required="required" type="email" ng-model="user.email">
    <label for="Password-2">Password:</label>
      <input class="text-field w-input" data-name="Password" id="Password-2" maxlength="256" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="required" type="password" ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-storage/0.0.15/angular-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
<script src="/Controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="/Controllers/testController.js"></script>
```

test.html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
Worked!

<script src="../js/express.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-storage/0.0.15/angular-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="../app.js"> </script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>
<script src="../controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="../controllers/testController.js"></script>
<script src="../controllers/signupController.js"></script>
</body>
```

Folder structure

```
/
controllers
 -loginController.js
 -testController.js
app.js
index.html
contact.html
info.html
dashboard
  -login.html
  -test.html
```

Comment: My guess would be because of the hash bang (#!) the URL is being sent to the .otherwise case in UI Router which is http://express.app/dashboard/login.html#!/.  When UI Router is loaded in login.html the hash bang is automatically added to the URL.  Do you need to load angular/UI Router at this point?  You could authenticate, send to index then load angular

Comment: I use a couple of helper libraries on the login page so I believe angularjs needs to be loaded and I believe to use state provider you have to load it

Comment: Instead of a $state.go("test") can you redirect to test with a vanilla solution, maybe something like this window.location = "http://expressapi.com/test.html"

Comment: Yes that works fine that is how I am doing it in the meantime until I can figure out why I can use state.go

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the UI router for a redirect the login.js functionality needs to be moved to the loginController file.  This is the controller the markup in login.html is attached to.

Comment: That was a typo on my part I meant to say login controller.js